# Sifr Horizontal Menu with LI

Tags: html, css, menu, sifr

I am designing a very simple horizontal menu with sIFR and CSS list. The thing about it is that it assigns a certain width to it that makes texts of different widths´ spacing look weird on screen.

I´ve seen a default width and height of a certain amount, but what I need is to make it so that the flash is exactly the size of the text.

Has anyone bumped into this issue before?

Thanks!

Comment: Will post it on Monday, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use fitExactly http://wiki.novemberborn.net/sifr3/JavaScript+Methods

> fitExactly (Boolean)
>       When true the dimensions of the Flash movie will fit exactly around
>   the width and height of the text in
>   the movie. *Note:* this is as reported
>   by Flash, so you might need to
>   manually tune the dimensions.

Though i would not suggest to use sIFR for links.